# How to cancel a GRPC streaming call?

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

Usually, the client can cancel the gRPC call with:

```
(requestObserver as ClientCallStreamObserver<Request>)
    .cancel("Cancelled", null)
```

However, it is shown in the [Javadoc](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/Context.html):

```
CancellableContext withCancellation = Context.current().withCancellation();
// do stuff
withCancellation.cancel(t);
```

Which one is the "correct" way of cancelling a client call, and letting the server know?

Edit:

To make matters more confusing, there's also `ManagedChannel.shutdown*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are acceptable and appropriate.

`clientCallStreamObserver.cancel()` is generally easier as it has less boilerplate. It should generally be preferred. However, it is not thread-safe; it is like normal sending on the StreamObserver. It also requires direct awareness with the RPC; you can't have higher-level code orchestrate the cancellation as it may not even be aware of the RPC.

Use `Context` cancellation for thread-safe cancellation and less RPC-aware cancellation. Context cancellation could be used in circumstances similar to thread interruption or Future cancellation. Not that `CancellableContext`s should be treated as a resource and must be cancelled eventually to avoid leaking memory. (`context.cancel(null)` can be used when the context reaches its "normal" end of life.)

Comment: `clientCallStreamObserver.cancel` may not be available if using a library that doesn't expose it; see this [discussion](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-kotlin/issues/32#issuecomment-668483982). Also, what about `channel.shutdown` (see edit)?

Comment: grpc-kotlin does not use the StreamObserver API at all; it uses the lower-level ClientCall directly for its stubs (which is appropriate). That's simply, "you aren't using the grpc-java stubs." `channel.shutdown()` does not cancel RPCs. `shutdownNow()` does, but it would be _very_ poor for cancelling individual RPCs.

Comment: "it uses the lower-level ClientCall " - Yes, I saw that in their code. It seems to be more of a pet project than a serious effort, questions and issues going unattended for days.